# Drag menu item to show web form

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in my web app (built in HTML5 and css), that will fill the whole screen. Right now when I click one menu item the app is showing a form. If I click on another item another form is visible. Instead of clicking on the menu item the goal is to drag the menu item to the left. When you start dragging the form starts to become visible from the right. (I had made a nice picture to explain it visually but I was not allowed to submit it :-( ). It should look like the form is attached to the menu items right side. The menu item itself should disappear under the left side of the screen while draggning. If you release the drag before you have come to the middle of the screen the form will disappear again, otherwise it will be fully visible.

I really need help with the css for attaching the form to the menu item. It you drag the item back and forth the item and the form should move together. Does anybody got a solution or a hint?

I think this is a pure css solution(?), but for information I am using angular and bootstrap for my app. In angular there is a module that includes hammer.js that might help me with the dragging, but I still need the css for the transition.

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: there is no CSS support for dragging items on the HTML. It's done with JS. There are enough examples on the internet to manage it

Comment: I have no code to post because I do not know how to make the form look like it is attached to the item.

Comment: I know there is many examples how to drag items, but I have not been able to find  any example how to drag two items at a time, to make the form look like it is attached to the items right side.